# How to save and store audio from a live stream?

Tags: javascript, audio, video-streaming, webrtc

On my website I have people use their phones as microphones, and ask a lecturer questions, which are then relayed to the surrounding audio system that is in the lecture hall. (Users connect via WebRTC)

However, I was wondering if there was a way to basically intercept and capture the audio that comes through the microphones and store it, so that students can access previous questions.

What would be the best ways to approach this? I looked at RecordRTC, but that only creates a new audio stream to play and records that, as opposed to allowing microphone access and recording automatically once the stream starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this recording library:
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

And an implementation of it on this blog post:
http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets

Comment: this is awesome! also i met you at hack reactor a couple of weeks ago and here you are answering my questions while i work on a project here! what are the chances of that

Comment: Oh wow no way! That's great man, hope you're learning a ton :) grab my email from someone around there if you have anymore questions.